# RTC not acknowledging slave address

Tags: timer, arm, embedded, real-time-clock

I'm writing a driver for m41t83 RTC IC and on AT91SAM7X (based on ARM7).

I'm trying to start communication with it over TWI (fast mode) and I have no response from the RTC (always get NACK).

I don't know what might cause the problem. Attached here some photoes to clock and data wires on oscilliscope where I send the RTC address 0x68 after the start condition and send write bit but receive a NACK.

I tryed ST's forum but in vain

Comment: Maybe you need to shift the slave address a bit?  If 0x68 is the 7-bit address, you may need to write 0xD0, or if its the 7-bit + r/w, maybe 0x34.  Some MCUs expect a special address register to have the 7 (or rarely used 10-bit) address written to it.  Others, you just write the "full" 8-bit (7+R/W).

Comment: Make sure what you see on the scope lines up with what you see in the datasheet for the RTC.

Comment: @Brian McFarland slave device address is 0xD0 and I shifted it right with one bit to be 0x68 as the controller expects 7bit address only in the register (there is no place for the eight bit in the register)